# Why is this not working simply because it's from $_POST?

Tags: php

I made a function earlier to go through a given string, and replace a select few characters such as é, ó, etc. with e, o, to get rid of foreign characters.

The function works fine when I set a string and use it like so:

```
$string = "Héllo";
echo replace_fc($string);
```

> Returns: Hello

However, when I take post data from an input box where I typed Héllo, like this:

```
$string = $_POST['words'];
echo replace_fc($string);
```

> returns HA�llo

It does not work.

Does anybody know why this might be? If I echo the POST data, it is exactly as I entered it (Héllo) and it shows on the page just fine. The function should not be outputting any special characters, just "Hello", so I can't see why it's messing up. The function is below. (P.S. Ignore my string/array system, I was doing that knowing that it is not optimal, I just did it for the funnies.)

```
function replace_fc($chars){
    //Hexadecimal characters separated by commas
    $hexes_str = "
        C0-A,C1-A,C2-A,C3-A,C4-A,C5-A,C6-A,                             "/* Capital A       */."
        E0-a,E1-a,E2-a,E3-a,E4-a,E5-a,E6-a,                             "/* Lowercase A     */."
        C8-E,C9-E,CA-E,CB-E,                                            "/* Capital E       */."
        E8-e,E9-e,EA-e,EB-e,                                            "/* Lowercase E     */."
        CC-I,CD-I,CE-I,CF-I,                                            "/* Capital I       */."
        EC-i,ED-i,EE-i,EF-i,                                            "/* Lowercase I     */."
        D2-O,D3-O,D4-O,D5-O,D6-O,D8-O,                                  "/* Capital O       */."
        F2-o,F3-o,F4-o,F5-o,F6-o,F8-o,                                  "/* Lowercase O     */."
        D9-U,DA-U,DB-U,DC-U,                                            "/* Capital U       */."
        F9-u,FA-u,FB-u,FC-u,                                            "/* Lowercase U     */."
        C7-C,D0-D,D1-N,D7-X,DD-Y,DF-B,DF-S,                             "/* Capital Misc    */."
        E7-c,F0-d,F1-n,D7-x,FD-y,FE-b,FF-y
    ";

    //Set them in to an array
    $hexes = explode(",", $hexes_str);
    //Remove spaces
    $hexes = array_map("trim", $hexes);

    //Empty array for all of my characters
    $numhtml = array();

    //For each of the numbers
    foreach($hexes as $x){
        //If $x is set to something (might be empty because of above explode, best to be safe)
        if($x){
            //Split them up
            $temp = explode("-",$x);
            //Stick them in the array
            $numhtml[$temp[1]][] = $temp[0];
        }
    }

    //Split the chars
    $chars_split = str_split($chars);

    //Set up empty vars to use
    $chars_enc = array(); $chars_result = null;

    //Get the urlencode versions
    foreach($chars_split as $x){
        $chars_enc[] = urlencode($x);
    }

    //For each of those
    foreach($chars_enc as $x){
        //If it has a % in it
        if(strpos($x, "%") !== false){
            //Get a version without the %
            $char = str_replace("%", "", $x);
            $replaced = false;

            //Go through the numhtml array
            foreach($numhtml as $key => $y){
                //If it has this char in it
                if(in_array($char, $y)){
                    //Add the key to the result
                    $chars_result .= $key;

                    //Set replaced to true
                    $replaced = true;
                }
            }

            //If replaced is still false
            if(!$replaced){
                //Add the original char
                $chars_result .= urldecode($x);
            }
        //If it is a space
        }elseif($x == "+"){
            $chars_result .= " ";
        //If there is no %, and it's not a space
        }else{
            //Then add it normally
            $chars_result .= $x;
        }
    }

    //Return the result
    return $chars_result;
}
```

Comment: This is a charset problem. Your input field is decoded in an other way than the file you are writing your code in.

Comment: I was about to +1 the answer as it helped me to solve it, but thank you, I've managed to fix this now. I'll post an answer to it, to show that it's done with.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted an answer here that helped me to solve this, but it's been removed so I'll explain what was said and what I did about it.

The answer informed me that $_POST encodes data automatically, and I've never seen this in action before as I've never dealt with UTF-8 and foreign characters until I decided to dabble today.

The way I got around this was to do the following:

```
$string = utf8_decode($_POST['words']);
$string = replace_fc($string); 
echo "$string<br />";
```

> utf8_decode() is the function that corrected the POST data so that I could use it.

Solved now, thank you to whomever it was that posted the answer.